# How to add dynamically a class with Thymeleaf?

Tags: css, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

could you help me please?

I'm trying to add  the class 'fixed-bottom' to a footer based on the lenght of an array using Thymeleaf.

This is a little part of the template.

```
<!-- footer -->
<div class="footer" th:classappend ="${ #list.size(clientes) < 4} ? 'fixed-bottom'">
    <footer th:replace="layout/layaout :: footer" ></footer>
</div>
<!-- footer Fin-->
```

And this is the method

```
@PostMapping("/buscar")
public String buscar( @RequestParam(name = "nombre") String nombre, Model model) {

    List<Cliente> clientes = clienteService.buscarPorNombre(nombre);

    // titulo
    model.addAttribute("titulo", "Resultado de busqueda");
    model.addAttribute("clientes", clientes);

    return "/resultados";
}
```

everything works well, but I got an error in this part, I guess that my syntax is wrong but I can't figure out where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work , the right helper is lists no list dude.

```
<!-- footer -->
    <div class="footer"
      th:classappend ="${#lists.size(clientes)} < 3 ? 'footer fixed-bottom'">
    <footer th:replace="layout/layaout :: footer" ></footer>
    </div>
    <!-- footer Fin-->
```